# ComponentDidMount() and state not updating with redux

Tags: redux

have this code snippet for a budget input and display. global state is updated in context and then repopulated in my display here "currentList" through component did mount.

the API updates but the page and state does not rerender. should i be using useEffect on the handle submit? when i try it tells me my dispatch is lost

```
  state = {
    expenses: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    API.getExpense().then((expenses) => {
      console.log(expenses.data);
      this.setState({ expenses: expenses.data });
    });
  }


  handleSubmit = (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'remove',
      expenses: this.state.expenses,
    })
    this.setState({
      expenses: [
        ...this.state.expenses
      ]
    });
    console.log(this.state.expenses)
  };


  deleteExpense = (id) => {
    API.deleteExpense(id)

  };



  currentList = () => {
    const currentList =
      this.state.expenses.length > 0 ? (
        this.state.expenses.map((expense, index) => {
          const { dispatch } = this.state;
          return (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{expense.expenseTitle}</td>
              <td>{expense.amount}</td>
              <td>{expense.category}</td>
              <td>
                <span className="delete-btn" role="button" id={expense._id} tabIndex="0" onClick={(e) => { this.deleteExpense(e.currentTarget.id) }} onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this, dispatch)}>
                  ✗
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
      ) : (
          <tr></tr>
        );
    return currentList;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='card mt-5' >
        <table className='table-bordered'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>title</th>
              <th>amount</th>
              <th>category</th>
              <th>remove</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <BudgetConsumer>
            {(value) => {
              // console.log(value.expenses);
              const expensesList =
                value.expenses.length > 0 ? (
                  value.expenses.map((expense, index) => {
                    const { dispatch } = this.state;
                    return (
                      <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{expense.expenseTitle}</td>
                        <td>{expense.amount}</td>
                        <td>{expense.category}</td>
                        <td>
                          <span className="delete-btn" role="button" id={expense._id} tabIndex="0" onClick={(e) => { this.deleteExpense(e.currentTarget.id) }} onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this, dispatch)}>
                            ✗
                        </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })
                ) : (
                    <tr></tr>
                  );
              return <tbody>{this.currentList()}{expensesList}</tbody>;
            }}
          </BudgetConsumer>
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
      </div >
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in the componentDidMount

```js
this.setState({expenses: [...expenses.data]});
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed, was thinkng too hard into the

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.expenses)
    API.getExpense().then((expenses) => {
      console.log(expenses.data);
      this.setState({ expenses: expenses.data });
    });
  }

  // call delete for the API then rerun the get expense API to reset the state
  deleteExpense = (id) => {
    API.deleteExpense(id).then(

      API.getExpense().then((expenses) => {
        console.log(expenses.data);
        this.setState({ expenses: expenses.data });
      })
    )
  };
```